# Ruby Errors: "Character Class has '[' without escape" AND "Premature end of character class"

Tags: ruby, regex, special-characters

For this line of code:

```
text = totaltext2.reject {|sentence| nilfacs.any?{|fac| sentence =~ /#{fac}/i}}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

1.) "Character Class has '[' without escape"

AND

2.) "Premature end of character class" followed by: 'in "each"', 'in "any?"', 'in "reject"', 'in '

Can anyone tell me what I need to change and/or what the problem is? I can't figure out what the error is.

Comment: "Nilfacs" is an array of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the strings inside 'fac' has unescaped regexp chars.

Comment: Would [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) help here? E.g. `sentence =~ /#{Regexp.escape(fac)}/i`.

Comment: So... One (or more) of the strings has characters that the regex is interpreting as instructions instead of just characters in a string, right? And escaping them will prevent this?
Just want to make sure I have the right idea.

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't seem to work. Now I get the error "undefined local variable or method 'regexp' for main:Object (NameError)"

Comment: @Thomas Did you capitalize `Regexp` in `Regexp.escape`?

Comment: I have now! Now that error is gone, thanks!
But now I'm getting "can't convert array to string". Hmm...